# Finding mean of user generated list

Tags: python

I'm trying to get an average of a list generated by a user. Everything works up until I try to do av = statistics...

I've tried spell checking. I've tried this code I found:

```
from statistics import mean 

def Average(lst): 
    return mean(lst) 

lst = [score_list] 
average = Average(lst) 

print("Average of the list =", round(average, 2))
```

my current code:

```
min = int(input("min: "))
max = int(input("max: "))
grades = list(range(min, max+1))
print (grades)

score_list = []
x = int(input("total students?: "))

while len(score_list) < x:
    score_list.append(input("enter scores: "))

print (score_list)

import statistics

av = statistics.mean(score_list)

print (av)
```

It always comes back

> TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator

I think its because the score_list is meaning used as a str not an int, but I can't find way to convert it without further errors.

Comment: You need to convert your entered scores to int as well as you already did this with your total students!

Comment: `score_list.append(int(input("enter scores: ")))`

Comment: Why was `Average` ever defined this way? If all you want is to use `Average` for `statistics.mean` you could just do: `Average = statistics.mean` or even `from statistics import mean as Average`. If you do it your way, you are adding an extra (generally "slow") function call, for no particularly good reason, at this level. Mind that adding an alias for a function from the standard library is considered bad practice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, `input()` returns str and not int. So if you change the line `score_list.append(input("enter scores: "))` to `score_list.append(int(input("enter scores: ")))` The program works correctly

Comment: Thank you so much, can't belive i missed such an obvious answer

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your scores are stored in str (each element).

```
score_list.append(int(input("enter score: ")))
```

try to cast it to int before appending it to a list. input now should receive only 1 value - this means enter after each score.

Or do it in such a way:

```
score_list += list(map(int, input("enter scores: ").split())
```

Operation `input().split()` will return a list of string scores (divide them by space character)

Operation `map(int, list)` will cast int on each element

Operation `list()` will cast the hole object to list, and it will be concatenated with other scores

I think it will give you what you want

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `input` reads strings and not intengers or floats. Therefore, you have to transform (cast) the datatype. In addition, try to work with `numpy` as it is one of the most common python libraries. This link can help you to get familiar with `numpy`: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-numpy-tutorial

**Solution**

```py
import numpy as np

min = int(input("min: "))
max = int(input("max: "))
grades = list(range(min, max+1))
print(grades)

score_list = []
x = int(input("total students?: "))

while len(score_list) < x:
    # Converting to float to use decimals as inpute
    grade = float(input("enter scores: "))
    score_list.append(grade)

print(score_list)

av = np.mean(score_list)
print(av)
```